# Interfacing data between functions in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a device that is connected to a Node server via WebSockets. To be able to query the device, a POST request to that server sends the necessary command via WebSockets. However, I'm not entirely sure what the best method of implenting getting the return is.

The flow is essentially:

- Device connects to Node server via WebSockets
- User sends POST request to endpoint on the same Node server
- Node server sends the suitable command to the device via WebSockets
- Device replies via WebSockets

This is where I'm stuck. How do I get the reply from WebSockets back to the POST request?

My first thoughts were as such:

- The POST request knows what command has been sent
- The device sends back the command as part of the WebSocket reply

Therefore, I can just have a simple array of messages from the device that the POST request function can poll, and if there's suitable reply (say within 2 seconds), reply with that data and delete the message from the array. Further down the line, I can delete any messages that have expired but are still in the array.

What are my other options? Presumably I could poll from the client doing the POST request or alternatively connect that client via a WebSocket.

This server supports 1 device and usually 1 user at a time, so there isn't really any worry that the server could become overwhelmed.

Comment: I opt for putting the user on their own websocket.